# How to sens and access parameters with POST method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm creating an authent form for my web page with Javascript and using Vue JS on client side and NodeJS with ExpressJS on server side.

On server side I writed my post method :

```
server.app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
})
```

On client side, I have my form on my html link to a Vue instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="authent">
      <p>Username :</p>
      <input type="text" name="username" v-model="username" required>
      <p>Pwd :</p>
      <input type="password" name="password" v-model="password" required>
      <button v-on:click="authent">Login</button>
    </div>
    <script src='/authent/vue.js'></script>
    <script src='/authent/vue-resource.min.js'></script>
    <script src="authent.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
  var authent = new Vue({
    el: '#authent',
    data: {
      username: null,
      password: null
    },
    methods: {
      authent: function() {
        try {
          this.$http.post('/login', {"username": authent.username, "password": authent.password})
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.body);
          })
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Apparently I wrongly send parameters in vue instance because on server side the `req.body` is undefined.

**EDIT**
Parameters are sent, but I don't know how I can access them in my post method on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you send it through ajax way. and you probably also send it as json object not a real post data. in express you should write (to have a json parser)

`app.use(express.json());`

and just to be safe. add a body parser too :-)

`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

you probably will need it too sooner or latter

just add the above middlewares

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Vue, but can you try to use `this.username` instead of `authent.username` ?

In your devTools, can you see that params has been seend ? To be sure that's a front-end issue.

Comment: this is not a front end issue indeed, parameters has been send